# Receiving unknown token into smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I was wondering if its possible to recognize one way or another a token that is sent to the smart contract, without token being previously registered?

Cheers, 
Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible off-chain, as one may monitor or query `Transfer` events.

In general, this is not possible to do on-chain, as token transfer do not leave any trace, so smart contract may not verify that some token transfer actually happened.  However, smart contact may verify that token balance of certain address (probably smart contract's own address) is non-zero now.  To do this, smart contract needs to know token contract address, for example transaction initiator may send this address to the smart contract in call parameters.

Comment: Ah! I see thanks for reply, truly appreciate :)